# Knockout - applying styles to the selected item in a Bootstrap Select

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

So this is piling libraries on top of libraries, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Our application has a number of drop-down elements all of which are [Bootstrap Select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) objects. These replace the standard set of option tags inside the select with a complex series of other elements that give you much greater control over the styling of the children and make them searchable.

Most of these objects exist as reusable components with an HTML view and a Typescript ViewModel, bound together with Knockout.

A number of these menus have icons next to the text. This is handled with optionsAfterRender. Here's an example.

View:

```
<select
  data-bind="options: items, 
            value: selectedValue, 
            optionsText: 'value',
            optionsValue: 'id',
            selectPicker: {},
            optionsAfterRender: applyOptionAttributes">
</select>
```

ViewModel:

```
export default class SelectComponent {

selectedValue: KnockoutObservable<string>;
items: KnockoutObservableArray<SelectOption>

  constructor(koObservable: KnockoutObservable<string>) {
    // items fetched and bound
  }

  applyOptionAttributes(option: Node, item: SelectOption): void {
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, { attr: { "data-content": `<img src="${item.iconurl}" />`, title: item.value } }, item);
  }
}

interface SelectOption {
    value: string;
    id: string
    iconurl: string;
}
```

And this is fine. However, because of the way Bootstrap Select styles the items inside it, the icon is not applied to the currently selected item - it's only displayed when the user clicks on the menu and it pops up.

Now, of course, we have a requirement to display the icon in currently selected item too. But I don't know how to get that element to bind to it. I can't fetch it directly because of the view-viewmodel pattern. It doesn't seem to be among the nodes passed by optionsAfterRender.

How can I get hold of it to style it?

EDIT: pretty sure this is a bug in bootstrap-select. Have raised an issue

https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2129

Comment: Are other Bootstrap styles being applied to the select prior to being clicked on? It sounds like there might be an issue with the `selectPicker()` being initialised after the render and thats missing the css paint.

Comment: @Levidps thanks for looking. There are classes on the select tag itself which I left off due to brevity, but nothing dynamic

Comment: My thought was more around the fact that `selectPicker` replaces some of the HTML structure so the initial classes are fine b/c they exist and html exists on initial draw. I'd be curious because the HTML structure is added after render, it's missing out on the initial CSS draw. e.x. ` DOM > CSS > selectPicker > new HTML elements` and now a new CSS paint doesn't occur until the user clicks on the select.

Comment: @Levidps Hmm. I think it's a bug in bootstrap-select. Have raised an issue on the project https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to fix this by preventing the post-processing of the options:

1. Replace the `options` binding with a `foreach` binding in the `select` element, binding each `option` with the appropriate ko-bindings.
2. Make sure the selectPicker binding has its [descendant bindings](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html) bound before calling `selectpicker` on the element.
3. Profit!

```js
ko.bindingHandlers['selectPicker'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
      $(element).selectpicker();
      return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
}

ko.applyBindings({
    selectedValue: ko.observable(3),
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Mustard', dc: '<span class="badge badge-warning">Mustard</span>' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Ketchup', dc: '<span class="badge badge-danger">Ketchup</span>' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Relish', dc: '<span class="badge badge-success">Relish</span>' }
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="selectPicker, value: selectedValue">
    <!-- ko foreach: options -->
    <option data-bind="text: name, attr: { value: id, 'data-content': dc }"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```