# Trouble getting dropdown value with knockout and bootstrap-selectpicker

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bootstrap-select, knockout-3.0

I've just started using knockout and I'm facing problems with grabbing the currently selected value in my dropdown.

Here is my custom handler so KO will work with the bootstrap-selectpicker and I can use the live search option.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectPicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        if ($(element).is('select')) { 
            if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
            }
            $(element).selectpicker();
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        if ($(element).is('select')) {
            var selectPickerOptions = allBindingsAccessor().selectPickerOptions;
            if (typeof selectPickerOptions !== 'undefined' && selectPickerOptions !== null) {
                var options = selectPickerOptions.options,
                    optionsText = selectPickerOptions.optionsText,
                    optionsValue = selectPickerOptions.optionsValue,
                    optionsCaption = selectPickerOptions.optionsCaption;
                if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options).length > 0) {
                    ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, options, ko.observable({ optionsText: optionsText, optionsValue: optionsValue, optionsCaption: optionsCaption }));
                }
            }
            if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor);
            }
            $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    }
};
```

Next I'm populating the dropdown from my database.

```
  function NewLoanViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.waitingLoanDutiesInfo = ko.observable(true);
            self.ErrorFromHandler = ko.observable("");
            self.offices = ko.observableArray([]);

LoadDDLs();

            function LoadDDLs() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/LoansX/KO/NewLoansHandler.ashx",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { mode: 'loaddls' },
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (typeof (data.e) != "undefined") {
                        self.ErrorFromHandler(data.e[0].description);
                    }
                    else {
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(data.d[0].offices, {}, self.offices);
                        self.waitingLoanDutiesInfo(false)
                    }
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    self.ErrorFromHandler(textStatus);
                    self.waitingLoanDutiesInfo(false)
                });
            }
}
```

Here is how my dropdown looks:

```
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: offices(),
            optionsText: 'IDNAME',
            optionsValue: 'ID',
            selectPicker: true"
            data-live-search="true">
            </select>
```

Lastly what I'm trying to do is grab the current value of my dropdown on a button click:

```
this.NewLoanClick = function () {
var LoanType = this.dgvtypes.optionsValue();
alert(LoanType);
}
```

So far I've tried doing NewLoanViewModel.dgvtypes.optionsValue, dgvtypes.optionsValue and so on, but most of them give me object property or method error.

Any tips would be greatly appreaciated, thanks.

Comment: I recently answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725553/4300023. It provides a different approach of binding `bootstrap-select` to `knockout`. Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Bootstrap Select picker, but the way to get the currently selected option from a select menu is simply using the `value` binding:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="
    options: offices(),
    optionsText: 'IDNAME',
    optionsValue: 'ID',
    selectPicker: true,
    value: selectedOffice" data-live-search="true"></select>
```

Obviously you'd have to create the observable `selectedOffice` on your viewmodel.

Also pretty sure you don't actually need most of the code in your binding handler. You need to call `$(element).selectpicker()` in the `init` method but that should be pretty much it.